# In PostgreSQL : FATAL: Could not access file "anon" , no such file or directory Error

Tags: postgresql

I have installed PostgreSQL13 version in my windows system and working though Pgadmin4 ,created one sample database like "Temp_Database". in that created one sample table "Agents". Agents table having ("AGENT_CODE", "AGENT_NAME", "WORKING_AREA", "COMMISSION", "PHONE_NO", "COUNTRY") columns. i want to perform masking concept on any one of the column. I tried some scripts and getting fatal error as mentioned below. ****Can anyone please help me to load anon() function in windows system****

--CREATE EXTENSION anon ;

ERROR:  could not open extension control file "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/13/share/extension/anon.control": No such file or directory
SQL state: 58P01

--ALTER DATABASE "Temp_Database" SET session_preload_libraries='anon';

ALTER DATABASE

Query returned successfully in 53 msec.

--SHOW session_preload_libraries;

FATAL: Could not access file "anon" , no such file or directory

Comment: `anon` does not come standard with PostgreSQL.  Did you install it?  And if so, how?

Comment: We did not install it. We were trying to implement it as given in this link: https://postgresql-anonymizer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/INSTALL/#addendum-alternative-ways-to-load-the-extension

Comment: That link says it is not supported on Windows.